# System restore always fails on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, system-restore

I'm trying to run system restore to go back to a restore points from two weeks ago. I tried running it from windows and running it from the advanced tools repair menu that appears right after launch. I always get the same error:

> System Restore could not access file. This probably because an
>   anti-virus program is running on the computer. Temporarily disable your anti-virus program
>   and retry

When I run the restore from the advanced tools screen windows hasn't even loaded yet, so there's no way (that I know of) that windows defender is running.

Does somebody know what to do here?

Comment: This indicates and sounds like the restoration point is corrupt.

Comment: I've tried will multiple restore points :S

Answer (score 0):

I have googled your error message, most of the answer is just temporarily disable the antivirus program and do the restoring . so better you can try like this.

Comment: I did. I also ran this without booting windows (from the troubleshoot startup screen)